# Dart websocket in dart:io and dart:html

Tags: websocket, dart, dart-html, dart-io

I have seen two implementation of websocket in `dart:io` and `dart:html`. Which one should I use? Currently I prefer more the websocket in `dart:io` since it seems to fit more naturally how dart handle streams and asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dart:html` library is used on the client-side and can be compiled to JavaScript.

Use `dart:io` for server-side code.

In a typical setup, you have a web server listening to WebSocket connections from the client, in which case you would use the one from `dart:html`. But of course you can also initiate WebSocket connections at the server if you ever need :)

Answer (score 3):

- `dart:io` is only available on the server
- `dart:html` is only available in the browser